Native American and dont speak spanish. How to explain
I live in Texas but I'm Native American and I grew up in Arizona on an Indian reservation. I LOOK like I should be able to speak Spanish and here, when people speak Spanish to me and hear me respond in English, they are honestly a little put off, because it looks like I am forgetting my roots.
What would be the best way to explain shortly in Spanish that I don't speak Spanish but it's because I am (Native American/Indian) because I haven't found a good short way to say (Native American/Indian)

Lo siento, pero como indio nativo, nunca aprendí a hablar español.

I look like I probably don't speak any Spanish, but I learned Spanish as a young child in Chile.  When I traveled to New Mexico, I found that I was often making the mistake you referred to, namely assuming a person of local heritage must be a Hispanic.  Don't apologize.  Just clear up the confusion.

The word indígena might also be helpful.

Lo cierto es que es imposible. Por experiencia, yo estuve por todo Miami y en ningún negocio al que iba me hablaron en inglés. Hay lugares en donde predomina el español. Aparte, la información que puedan obtener por lo no verbal siempre va a ganar. Te van a asumir hispano, más aún en un país que ni siquiera tiene idioma oficial. Pero estoy de acuerdo con Walter, no creo que le debas disculpas a nadie.

Soy amerindio no hispano. Amerindian is a good word.

El problema no es Ud. sino la manía de la mayor parte de la población en Estados Unidos de asumir que la persona habla tal o cual idioma o lengua porque su aspecto exterior se ve similar a tal o cual grupo humano.
Solo diga "no hablo español", no tiene porqué justificarse.

There are many straightforward ways to say this, for instance:

Soy indígena, así que el español no es mi lengua materna/primer idioma.


I am Native American, so Spanish is not my first language.

Or, as someone suggested in the comments:

Soy indígena y no hablo español.


I am Native American and I do not speak Spanish.

Note: The word "indígena" is often considered the most respectful way to say "Native American" in Latin American Spanish these days, paralleling the rise of "Indigenous" in English. If you wanted to really specify that you are from the USA (and not, say, a country where Spanish is widely spoken among Indigenous groups), you could say "indígena estadounidense" or "indígena norteamericano," although it might come off as a little formal (note that "norteamericano" technically applies to Mexico, Central America and so forth, but a lot of Spanish speakers will understand it as a reference to the large Anglo-American countries in North America, i.e. the USA and Canada). Nonetheless, if you called yourself "indio" (Indian), there also would be little risk of confusion in that context (but there might be in other contexts, e.g. at the United Nations).
You could also use a literal "nativo americano" (i.e. "soy un nativo americano"); while this might seem like an Anglicism to some people, it is used in some Spanish-speaking sources and circles in the USA and will be generally understood, at least among Spanish speakers born in the USA. I am not sure how useful it would be in all places when traveling, however. If you know the person you are talking to is particularly well-informed, you could certainly get more specific: if you are Apache or Hopi, for instance, you could certainly say "soy apache/hopi/etcetera" (though the pronunciation of these words that they are used to might be a little different from that which most non-Indigenous English-speaking Americans would be used to, naturally).
That said,  the linguistic issue is obviously only part of it; there is obviously a larger interpersonal issue here with interacting with someone who feels that it is appropriate to make people feel bad for not speaking the language that some of their forebears spoke (something that applies to a very large percentage of Americans), even though they have guessed that language incorrectly in your case. How you choose to engage with that assumption, if at all, is obviously a personal decision, but it might be worth keeping in mind nonetheless.

There's also amerindio.

@Lambie - True, but I am not sure about how widely it would be understood (and precisely how it would be understood—would they understand as only the USA or the whole continent(s)?), so I did not mention it. But it is certainly another option.
